# Can I use titlesec to make a line under every section title at the linewidth?

Tags: latex

I want to underline every section title in a document with a line at the linewidth.

From my undrestanding this should be possible using titlesec but when I put :

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\titleline*[c]{\titlerule[.8pc]{.}}}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titlerule[1pc]{.}}
```

However, nothing happens. I played around a bit with the syntax, but nothing happens. Also, I get no error messages. Am I forgetting some (empty) arguments?

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2.5mm}{0mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titleline*[c]{\titlerule[.8pc]{.}}}
\titleformat*{\section}{\titlerule[1pc]{.}}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section*{second section}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section*{third}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't do that yet; I have the code but how do I add a code block? (new to this editor)
edit; nevermind,; it's in the op

Answer (score 0):

Using the optional `after-code` argument might be the easiest way to add a line after each section title:

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2.5mm}{0mm}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule\vspace*{4pt}]


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section*{second section}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section*{third}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```